# Interval of convexity without using derivatives

Tags: calculus, analysis, convex-analysis

I have to find all the values of $\lambda$ real for which is convex the following function, not everywhere differentiable.

$$f(x) = |x| - \lambda \ln(|x|+7)$$

I cannot use derivatives, but only properties and occasional compositions. The reason why I cannot use derivatives is just a demand. We need to be used to the fact that derivatives must be the last help possible. We can use properties like continuity, elementary functions (for example that $e^x$ is convex and so on) and propositions about compositions of functions, for example the well known facts that, say, the composition between a convex function and a linear one is convex, or the composition between a concave decreasing function and a convex one is concave, and so on.

Yet for this exercise I'm stuck for nothing seems to help.

**Attempts**

Well, sum of convex function is convex. Since |x| is convex, I need to fins when $ - \lambda \ln(|x|+7)$ is convex.

I thought that for $\lambda > 0$ the function $- \lambda \ln(|x|+7)$ is convex everywhere, but then by plotting a doubt arose: here is the manipulate plot for $a$ (the $\lambda$ in our case)

[image]

So there is a part in which from a certain $a$ onwards, the function is convex. But I don't understand how exactly to work it out.

Our professor told us about convexity and concavity with the metaphor "valleys and bridges", and for example in the above plot I see two valleys but also one bridge.

I would also say that there is a cusp, but does it matter? I'm confused...

Comment: A translation of $\ln(|x|)$ would be $\ln(|x+7|)$, but $\ln(|x|+7)$ is *not* a translation of that function.

Comment: @MartinR Well, you're bloody right!

Comment: Checking if $f'$ is increasing seems an easy and very natural way to me here.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, to me too. But our professor explicitely demanded to avoid derivatives... Indeed I got stuck on how to exactly proceed, ugh.

Comment: The answer is $\lambda \in [0,7]$.

Comment: @copper.hat And the reasoning to conclude this?

Comment: $\lambda <0$ results in a concave function. The epigraph is symmetric about the $y$ axis. For $\lambda >7$ the epigraph is not convex and it is convex otherwise. Frankly, reasoning without derivatives (or rather one sided derivatives) is painful.

Comment: @copper.hat $\lambda < 0$ doesn't result in a concave function, if you mean it on $\mathbb{R}$. It's concave on $(-\infty, 0)$ and on $(0, +\infty)$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Numb3rs Excuse my imprecision. Yes, that is what I meant. Since it is concave for $x>0$ it eliminates $\lambda <0$ which is all I was thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

Your picture is quite helpful at eliminating cases. Due to the symmetry of the problem, lets consider $f(\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}(-x))=f(0)=-\lambda\ln(7)$ and compare this with $\frac{1}{2}f(x)+\frac{1}{2}f(-x)=f(x)=x-\lambda\ln(x+7)$ for any $x\geq 0$. Convexity require $$x\geq \lambda\ln(\frac{x}{7}+1)$$

$\log(x/7+1)> 0$ so we need

$$\frac{x}{\ln(\frac{x}{7}+1)}\geq \lambda$$

Let $g(x):=\frac{x}{\ln(\frac{x}{7}+1)}$, this function is increasing. So lets look what happens at $g(0)$. $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{1/(x+7)}=7$. What can we conclude here? that $\lambda$ must be less than 7. Note that this is necessary, its not suffient.

Comment: Still don't get how you derived that the condition is just necessary but not sufficient...

Comment: To show its convex you have to show $f(ax+(1-a)y)\leq af(x)+(1-a)f(y)$ for all $x,y$ and all $a\in [0,1]$. I just considered $x=y$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}$. By just considering these subcases we eliminated $\lambda>7$ from consideration.

Comment: Yes, that I got. But $\lambda \leq 7$ could mean everything. I am thinking of how to obtain $\lambda \in [0, 7]$

Comment: That is just why its a necessary condition. All I showed is that if $f$ is convex then $\lambda\leq 7$.